# How to set mysql update value which from other select

Tags: mysql

In my project, I have table IDCA and IDCB.

I  cat query sql like:

```
$liId=99;
select name from  IDCA  where stId='$liId';
```

And the result is:

```
John
Stack
Shansa
Aliya
Stock
```

Then I set allName of IDCB with these values.

```
update IDCB set allName=(select name from  IDCA  where stId='$liId') where stId='$liId';
```

But it works fail. And error is:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Actually, I want set  allName='John,Stack,Shansa,Aliya,Stock'. So who can help me?

Comment: Try this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```sql
update IDCB set allName=(
    select GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
    from  IDCA  
    where stId='$liId' GROUP BY stId)
where stId='$liId';
```